# postman testing on 'response body contains string' does not work

Tags: testing, postman

To narrow down the problem, I change the response body into something as simple as one sentence as text/plain.

```
this is a test
```

However, the following very basic function still fails:

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("this");
```

Ironically this test works:

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("t");
```

I am using the latest postman v4.11.1. It looks like a fundamental defect for postman.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that postman does not support unicode. if i change the encoding to utf-8, everything works perfectly.